# Encoding special characters for passing to a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode, omdbapi

I am trying to learn Python, so I thought I would start by trying to query IMDB to check my movie collection against IMDB; which was going well

What I am stuck on is how to handle special characters in names, and encode the name to something a URL will respect.

For example I have the movie `Brüno`

If I encode the string using  `urllib.parse.quote` I get - `Bru%CC%88no`  which means when I query IMDB using OMDBAPI it fails to find the movie.  If I do the search via the OMDBAPI site, they encode the name as `Br%C3%BCno` and this search works.

I am assuming that the encode is using a different standard, but I can’t work out what I need to do

Comment: This is actually a bug on IMDB’s side (this doesn’t immediately help *you*, of course).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - just out of curiosity, why would this be considered a bug on IMDB's side? Is there a standard or other reason that NFC form should not be used in url encoding?

Comment: @benvc The search API shouldn’t assume any one input normalisation, and instead perform its own, or otherwise ensure that relevant results are found regardless of how input is normalised: The Unicode standard is entirely clear on this: “Brüno” = “Brüno”, even if the first string uses a dedicated codepoint and the second uses a combining diacritic. Comparison must happen on the level of grapheme clusters, not on the level of bytes or codepoints.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - makes sense, thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is using the same *encoding*, but using different normalizations.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> "Brüno".encode("utf-8")
b'Bru\xcc\x88no'
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFC", "Brüno").encode("utf-8")
b'Br\xc3\xbcno'
```

Some graphemes (things you see as one "character"), especially those with diacritics can be made from different characters. An "ü" can either be a "u", with a combining diaresis, or the character "ü" itself (the combined form). Combined forms don't exist for every combination of letter and diacritic, but they do for commonly used ones (= those existing in common languages).

Unicode normalization transforms all characters that form graphemes into either combined or seperate characters. The normalization method "NFC", or *Normalization Form Canonical Composition*, combines characters as far as possible.

In comparison, the other main form, *Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition*, or "NFD" will produce your version:

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFD", "Brüno").encode("utf-8")
b'Bru\xcc\x88no'
```

Comment: Technically the result of a normalisation *is* an encoding. “Encoding” in the context of Unicode (as in your answer) often refers to the different UTFs (i.e. the encoding of code points) but the meaning of encoding is more general. `Br%C3%BCno` and `Bru%CC%88no` are two different encoded forms of the information “Brüno”.

Comment: As a minor addition that may be useful to some, you can also explicitly get the comparable NFD output, `b'Bru\xcc\x88no'`, using `unicodedata.normalize("NFD", "Brüno").encode("utf-8")` to illustrate which normalization form is being used in each instance.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes and no: The result of normalisation is still an instance of `str`, not `bytes`, it only changes which unicode codepoints are used. Nothing is declared about how these are represented yet. But yes, all strings in a computer are encoded somehow, even "Unicode strings".